# scroll inside fixed scollable tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in my HTML code  i have a tab i want this tab always visible when scrolling that's for i added a java script function to do it .
this is my js function :

```
if ($(window).width() < 991) {
function sticky_relocate() {
var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
if (window_top > div_top) {
    $('#alwaysvisible').addClass('stick');
    $('#sticky-anchor').height($('#alwaysvisible').outerHeight());
            } else {
                $('#alwaysvisible').removeClass('stick');
                $('#sticky-anchor').height(0);
            }
        }


        $(function () {
            $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
            sticky_relocate();
        });
    }
```

html

```
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                                <div class="sides_margin sides_margin2">
                                    <div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
                                    <div id="alwaysvisible" class="rblk col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 categoriesWrapper">
                                        <div class="btitle ">
                                            <div class="bg"></div>
                                            <div class="px"></div>
                                            <div class="padd categories"><h4 class="visible-lg categoriesh4">{{'categories'|trans }}</h4></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="scrollablediv" class="categoryListWrapper">
                                            <ul>
                                                {% for category in catArray %}                
                                                    <li><a href="{{ category.link|raw }}" title="{{ category.name|raw }}">{{ category.name|raw }}</a></li>                          
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        {% for whereis in whereisAll%} 
                                            <div class="btitleWhereis margintop10 hidden-md hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                                                <a class="whereislink" href="{{ whereis.link|raw }}" title="{{ whereis.name|raw }}">
                                                    <div class="bg"></div>
                                                    <div class="px"></div>
                                                    <div class="padd categories"><h4 class="visible-lg categoriesh4">{{ whereis.name|raw }}</h4></div>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        {% endfor %}

                                    </div>
                                </div>
           </div>
```

css

```
#alwaysvisible.stick {
margin-top: 0 !important;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 10;
float: right;
padding-left: 0;
width: 10%;
padding-right: 10px; 
}
```

but the problem is that i have a lot of content in the tab content with a fixed position not all the content are shown , i tried to add a new class  on scroll and giving the content an overflow-y:scroll but it doesn't work (the content is not visible anymore ) so what i should do in order to make it work and the content scroll is the best solution for this ? or their is a best way to make it happen ?

thanks in advance